# Why does git flow release finish merge the tag onto develop as the last step

Tags: git, git-flow

I am trying to finish a release using git flow but am running into some strange issues. 
When i do a `git flow release finish -m "msg" <release_version>` it updates all branches fine but it does an additional step of merging the tag onto develop.

I used the following commands to replicate the scenario using plain git.

1. git checkout master
2. git merge --no-ff release/1.2.0
3. git tag -a 1.2.0
4. git checkout develop
5. git merge --no-ff release/1.2.0
6. git branch -d release/1.2.0
7. git checkout master

At the end of these commands i see everything is updated fine. 
However when i add a command `git merge [tag_name]` i land up in the same state as i do when doing the git flow.

I do have one machine where i do not see this problem. 
The only difference is i have git for 32 bit installed on that one.
All the ones that have git for 64 bit show the same error.

Comment: [Thomas.F](https://stackoverflow.com/users/5559182) posted an [Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/66246082) saying "I know it's old but I got the same problem and the origin was that: https://github.com/nvie/gitflow/issues/6400#issuecomment-364173201"